# I have a QR Code generator script that runs but didn't work in Flask

Tags: python, flask, qr-code

The following code works fine and generates me a functional QR Code:

```
import qrcode

ssid = "Matheus-5G"
password = "*****"
security = "WPA" 

wifi_data = f"WIFI:T:{security};S:{ssid};P:{password};;"

qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version = 1, 
    error_correction = qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L, 
    box_size = 10, 
    border = 4 
)

print(wifi_data)
qr.add_data(wifi_data)
qr.make(fit=True) 

img = qr.make_image(fill_color = 'black', back_color = 'white') 
img.save("qrcode_wifi.png")
img.show()
```

---

Now, the SAME script using Flask, also generates me a QR Code but not functional "no data available". I printed the variables and they are just fine and the same as they should be.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
import qrcode
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def inicio():
    if os.path.exists("static/qrcode_wifi.png"):
        os.remove("static/qrcode_wifi.png")
    return render_template('index.html', titulo='Wi-Fi QR Code Generator')


@app.route('/criar', methods=['POST'])
def criar():

    ssid = request.form['ssid']
    password = request.form['password']
    security = request.form['security']
  
    wifi_data = f"WIFI:T:{security};S:{ssid};P:{password};;"

    print(wifi_data)
    print(ssid)
    print(password)
    print(security)

    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version = 1, 
        error_correction = qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H, 
        box_size = 10, 
        border = 4 
    )

    qr.add_data(wifi_data)
    qr.make() 

    img = qr.make_image(fill_color = 'black', back_color = 'white') 
    img.save("static/qrcode_wifi.png")

    return render_template('index.html', titulo='Wi-Fi QR Code Generator', qr_code_image_data=url_for('static', filename='qrcode_wifi.png'))

app.run(debug=True)
```

Any idea? The scripts are the same and when I print the variables I'm getting the same result in both, but one QR Code works just fine and the others doesn't.

Comment: My INDEX in case you need it

Comment: `img.save("static/qrcode_wifi.png")` This saves the image in a subfolder of **the current directory**.  Are you sure that is the correct place?  The current directory is **not** necessarily the same directory as the python script file.

Comment: You can use this code to see the actual current directory `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Yes, the directory is correct. I even opened the QR Code directly at the windows explorer window and it's updating correctly. The problem's that the QR isn't getting the correct data apparently

Comment: Those two codes aren't exactly the same.  One uses `qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L` and  `qr.make(fit=True)`, and the other uses `qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H` and `qr.make()`.